How to correctly resolve window style value to macro text?
I wrote a code to resolve a window style value to text macro, but the output is wildly different from the style value; why and how to fix it?
output:

WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_3STATE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | BS_OWNERDRAW | BS_TYPEMASK | SS_ETCHEDVERT | SS_OWNERDRAW | SS_TYPEMASK |

code:
#include <windows.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class StyleMapSingleton {
private:
    std::unordered_map<DWORD, std::wstring> styleMap;
    StyleMapSingleton() {
        styleMap = {
            {WS_OVERLAPPED,         L"WS_OVERLAPPED"},
            {WS_POPUP,              L"WS_POPUP"},
            {WS_VISIBLE,            L"WS_VISIBLE"},
            {WS_CHILD,              L"WS_CHILD"},
            {WS_MINIMIZE,           L"WS_MINIMIZE"},
            {WS_DISABLED,           L"WS_DISABLED"},
            {WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,       L"WS_CLIPSIBLINGS"},
            {WS_CLIPCHILDREN,       L"WS_CLIPCHILDREN"},
            {WS_MAXIMIZE,           L"WS_MAXIMIZE"},
            {WS_BORDER,             L"WS_BORDER"},
            {WS_DLGFRAME,           L"WS_DLGFRAME"},
            {WS_VSCROLL,            L"WS_VSCROLL"},
            {WS_HSCROLL,            L"WS_HSCROLL"},
            {WS_SYSMENU,            L"WS_SYSMENU"},
            {WS_THICKFRAME,         L"WS_THICKFRAME"},
            {WS_GROUP,              L"WS_GROUP"},
            {WS_TABSTOP,            L"WS_TABSTOP"},
            {WS_MINIMIZEBOX,        L"WS_MINIMIZEBOX"},
            {WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,        L"WS_MAXIMIZEBOX"},

            {BS_PUSHBUTTON,         L"BS_PUSHBUTTON"},
            {BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,      L"BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON"},
            {BS_RADIOBUTTON,        L"BS_RADIOBUTTON"},
            {BS_CHECKBOX,           L"BS_CHECKBOX"},
            {BS_3STATE,             L"BS_3STATE"},
            {BS_AUTO3STATE,         L"BS_AUTO3STATE"},
            {BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,       L"BS_AUTOCHECKBOX"},
            {BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,    L"BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON"},
            {BS_GROUPBOX,           L"BS_GROUPBOX"},
            {BS_USERBUTTON,         L"BS_USERBUTTON"},
            {BS_BITMAP,             L"BS_BITMAP"},
            {BS_ICON,               L"BS_ICON"},
            {BS_FLAT,               L"BS_FLAT"},
            {BS_MULTILINE,          L"BS_MULTILINE"},
            {BS_OWNERDRAW,          L"BS_OWNERDRAW"},
            {BS_PUSHLIKE,           L"BS_PUSHLIKE"},
            {BS_LEFT,               L"BS_LEFT"},
            {BS_RIGHT,              L"BS_RIGHT"},
            {BS_CENTER,             L"BS_CENTER"},
            {BS_TOP,                L"BS_TOP"},
            {BS_BOTTOM,             L"BS_BOTTOM"},
            {BS_VCENTER,            L"BS_VCENTER"},
            {BS_RIGHTBUTTON,        L"BS_RIGHTBUTTON"},
            {BS_LEFTTEXT,           L"BS_LEFTTEXT"},
            {BS_TEXT,               L"BS_TEXT"},
            {BS_NOTIFY,             L"BS_NOTIFY"},
            {BS_TYPEMASK,           L"BS_TYPEMASK"},

            {CBS_AUTOHSCROLL,       L"CBS_AUTOHSCROLL"},
            {CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL,   L"CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL"},
            {CBS_DROPDOWN,          L"CBS_DROPDOWN"},
            {CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,      L"CBS_DROPDOWNLIST"},
            {CBS_HASSTRINGS,        L"CBS_HASSTRINGS"},
            {CBS_LOWERCASE,         L"CBS_LOWERCASE"},
            {CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT,  L"CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT"},
            {CBS_OEMCONVERT,        L"CBS_OEMCONVERT"},
            {CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED,    L"CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED"},
            {CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE, L"CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE"},
            {CBS_SIMPLE,            L"CBS_SIMPLE"},
            {CBS_SORT,              L"CBS_SORT"},

            {ES_AUTOHSCROLL,        L"ES_AUTOHSCROLL"},
            {ES_AUTOVSCROLL,        L"ES_AUTOVSCROLL"},
            {ES_LEFT,               L"ES_LEFT"},
            {ES_CENTER,             L"ES_CENTER"},
            {ES_RIGHT,              L"ES_RIGHT"},
            {ES_LOWERCASE,          L"ES_LOWERCASE"},
            {ES_UPPERCASE,          L"ES_UPPERCASE"},
            {ES_OEMCONVERT,         L"ES_OEMCONVERT"},
            {ES_NUMBER,             L"ES_NUMBER"},
            {ES_PASSWORD,           L"ES_PASSWORD"},
            {ES_MULTILINE,          L"ES_MULTILINE"},
            {ES_WANTRETURN,         L"ES_WANTRETURN"},
            {ES_NOHIDESEL,          L"ES_NOHIDESEL"},
            {ES_READONLY,           L"ES_READONLY"},

            {SS_BLACKFRAME,         L"SS_BLACKFRAME"},
            {SS_GRAYFRAME,          L"SS_GRAYFRAME"},
            {SS_WHITEFRAME,         L"SS_WHITEFRAME"},
            {SS_ETCHEDFRAME,        L"SS_ETCHEDFRAME"},
            {SS_ETCHEDHORZ,         L"SS_ETCHEDHORZ"},
            {SS_ETCHEDVERT,         L"SS_ETCHEDVERT"},
            {SS_BLACKRECT,          L"SS_BLACKRECT"},
            {SS_WHITERECT,          L"SS_WHITERECT"},
            {SS_GRAYRECT,           L"SS_GRAYRECT"},
            {SS_CENTERIMAGE,        L"SS_CENTERIMAGE"},
            {SS_REALSIZEIMAGE,      L"SS_REALSIZEIMAGE"},
            {SS_REALSIZECONTROL,    L"SS_REALSIZECONTROL"},
            {SS_LEFT,               L"SS_LEFT"},
            {SS_CENTER,             L"SS_CENTER"},
            {SS_RIGHT,              L"SS_RIGHT"},
            {SS_RIGHTJUST,          L"SS_RIGHTJUST"},
            {SS_EDITCONTROL,        L"SS_EDITCONTROL"},
            {SS_SIMPLE,             L"SS_SIMPLE"},
            {SS_SUNKEN,             L"SS_SUNKEN"},
            {SS_ENDELLIPSIS,        L"SS_ENDELLIPSIS"},
            {SS_PATHELLIPSIS,       L"SS_PATHELLIPSIS"},
            {SS_WORDELLIPSIS,       L"SS_WORDELLIPSIS"},
            {SS_ICON,               L"SS_ICON"},
            {SS_BITMAP,             L"SS_BITMAP"},
            {SS_ENHMETAFILE,        L"SS_ENHMETAFILE"},
            {SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP,     L"SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP"},
            {SS_NOPREFIX,           L"SS_NOPREFIX"},
            {SS_NOTIFY,             L"SS_NOTIFY"},
            {SS_OWNERDRAW,          L"SS_OWNERDRAW"},
            {SS_TYPEMASK,           L"SS_TYPEMASK"},
        };
    }
    StyleMapSingleton(const StyleMapSingleton&) = delete;
    void operator=(const StyleMapSingleton&) = delete;
public:
    static StyleMapSingleton& getInstance() {
        static StyleMapSingleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    const std::unordered_map<DWORD, std::wstring>& getStyleMap() const {
        return styleMap;
    }
};

void resolveWindowStyle(DWORD style, const std::unordered_map<DWORD, std::wstring>& styleMap) {
    for (const auto& entry : styleMap) {
        if (style & entry.first) {
            std::wcout << entry.second << L" | ";
        }
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    const auto& styleMapInst = StyleMapSingleton::getInstance();
    DWORD style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_CENTER;
    resolveWindowStyle(style, styleMapInst.getStyleMap());
    return 0;
}


Have you tried to debug your program? Like stepping through it line by line in a debugger while monitoring variables and their values?

Hint: some values in your map share some bits.

If you look at the actual values for the different styles you will notice that they share the same values in many cases. That is because they are not generally used together: styles beginning with WS are Windows styles, BS are buttons, CBS combobox etc.

The solution depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish. Besides the fact that some constants re-use the same bits used by others, for different window classes, there's also the case of the WS_OVERLAPPED window style (with a value of 0). That needs special treatment and also depends on your ultimate goal.

Many of the styles you are keeping track of have the same numeric values. They are not unique globally, as you are assuming. They are unique only to each window class that defines them.
So, you need to first differentiate between classes before you can then differentiate between styles. Thus, in order to log the styles correctly, you need to have a window and know what class type it is using.
Have a look at RealGetWindowClass() to help you with that task.
Also see:

What's the difference between RealGetWindowClass and GetClassName? (or what is a "Window type" versus a "Window class name"?)

What makes RealGetWindowClass so much more real than GetClassName?




The constants are not guaranteed to be unique. For example ES_CENTER shares its value (1) with three other, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, CBS_SIMPLE and SS_CENTER. Since the Key in an unordered_map must be unique, only one of them is stored. You may want to use a multimap in order to be able to display all constants.

Some constants have more than one bit set. A constant like SS_TYPEMASK that shows up in your list has the value 31, which has 5 bits set. These can also be shared with other constants.


For both these reasons, it's impossible to make the mapping back to the exact constants you used. The relationship is not bijective.

SS_TYPEMASK is a mask, not a style constant. Regardless, the styles have a unique, canonical representation, just not in isolation. You need to know the window class for disambiguation.

@IInspectable Yes, I know, and the same for BS_TYPEMASK. Yes, the map could have another layer where you'd select which of the sets you'd like to consider. It'd still be impossible to know if the user supplied BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_CHECKBOX or BS_AUTOCHECKBOX but perhaps then only displaying the names for the single or zero bit constants would be good enough.
